# Microsoft Edge not accepting hashes for Content-Security Policy

Tags: javascript, css, security, content-security-policy, microsoft-edge

**The problem**

Content-Security-Policy should blacklist script and style parsing by default and allow it based on various instructions of which one is verified a hash of the expected output. The browser must fail to implement any Javascript or CSS which has not been given a matching hash in advance. Code with a matching hash should be executed as normal. Microsoft Edge is refusing all JS/CSS in-page blocks.

- **Instructions** Visit the live demonstration link below in Microsoft Edge, and also in any other browser.
- **Live demonstration:** http://output.jsbin.com/biqidoqebu

**Demonstration original source code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'sha256-JtUhvM7uQO2KX5IEGWxN+rhEyzzsyFelfO2gXvYEuWA='; script-src https://ajax.googleapis.com 'sha256-iZzrsbzuGxfOaTdnB/E6RQBssyXQRp7W8YtZD2Wg/Rc=';" />
<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'sha256-JtUhvM7uQO2KX5IEGWxN+rhEyzzsyFelfO2gXvYEuWA='; script-src https://ajax.googleapis.com 'sha256-iZzrsbzuGxfOaTdnB/E6RQBssyXQRp7W8YtZD2Wg/Rc=';" />
<style>#loading{color:transparent}#loading:after{color:green;content:"Style loaded."}</style>
</head>
<body>
<span id="loading">Hashes loading...</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>alert("Script loaded.")</script>
```

- **Expected behaviour:** The body should change to "Style loaded.", an alert box should say "Script loaded.", external Javascript should not throw an error. Console shows no issues.
- **Actual behaviour:** Body stuck on "Hashes loading...". Hashes refused, external Javascript accepted. Console shows errors:

`CSP14304: Unknown source ‘'sha256-JtUhvM7uQO2KX5IEGWxN+rhEyzzsyFelfO2gXvYEuWA='’ for directive ‘style-src’ in  - source will be ignored.`

`CSP14306: No sources given for directive ‘style-src’ for  - this is equivalent to using ‘none’ and will prevent the downloading of all resources of this type.`

`CSP14304: Unknown source ‘'sha256-iZzrsbzuGxfOaTdnB/E6RQBssyXQRp7W8YtZD2Wg/Rc='’ for directive ‘script-src’ in  - source will be ignored.`

`CSP14312: Resource violated directive ‘style-src 'sha256-JtUhvM7uQO2KX5IEGWxN+rhEyzzsyFelfO2gXvYEuWA='’ in : inline style. Resource will be blocked.`

`CSP14312: Resource violated directive ‘script-src LINK-REMOVED-INSUFFICIENT-REPUTATION-ON-STACKOVERFLOW-SHOULD-BE-THE-GOOGLE-API-URL 'sha256-iZzrsbzuGxfOaTdnB/E6RQBssyXQRp7W8YtZD2Wg/Rc='’ in : inline script. Resource will be blocked.`

**Attempted fixes**

- **Verifying the hashes are correct:** Double-checked calculation was binary, that's about it. Not much to do, other browsers are accepting them.
- **Changed values** of `default-src` and `connect-src` to `self` rather than `none`

I can't think of anything else to try.

**Update 24 hours later:** Added X-Content-Security-Policy for completeness & JSBin URL updated, though it doesn't make a difference to this particular situation.

Comment: does internet explorer support this?

Comment: you should use an actual http header.

Comment: have you tried `style-src self 'sha256-JtUhvM7uQO2KX5IEGWxN+rhEyzzsyFelfO2gXvYEuWA='`  or `style-src URL_OF_YOUR_PAGE 'sha256-JtUhvM7uQO2KX5IEGWxN+rhEyzzsyFelfO2gXvYEuWA='` ?

Comment: @Daniel A. White - The issue does not occur in IE11.The page is dynamically created and then cached server-side, so http-headers aren't possible. Though, presumably, you'd want the headers in-page if they are ever loaded from client cache as well. It should make no difference, browsers clearly deal with it just fine.

Comment: @ben Yes, domain instead of self doesn't help. I'm sure that should only be applied to separate requests anyway.

Comment: @oreoshake IE11 *does* understand CSP including hashes, as does Opera and probably more. In fact, IE11 on Windows 10 no longer uses the X- prefix. I've updated the JSBin URL to include the X-CSP header, try it yourself. This is why it's puzzling me so much, it appears support has been removed for the newer browser.

Comment: p.s. I deleted my potential misinformation outlined below:  "only chrome supports nonces/hashes AFAIK as of 31/7/2015" AND "that's because IE 11 doesn't understand content-security-policy. Props on using hashes :) "

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: this may be incorrect. See comments above.

IE 11 does not support `Content-Security-Policy` (only `X-Content-Security-Policy`), this fails open.
IE 12 supports CSP, but does not grok nonces/hashes, it fails closed... unless you also supply `'unsafe-inline'` in a `Content-Security-Policy` header.

CSP level 2 says "if a hash or nonce is supplied, ignore `'unsafe-inline'`." this is for backwards compatibility since older browsers will grok the `'unsafe-inline'` but not the nonces/hashes. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-script-src

Comment: The explanation may not quite be on the money, but adding 'unsafe-inline' is the solution. I didn't know it degraded gracefully, at least the site works again. I don't think there is an explanation, I'm guessing unintentional feature regression. I've reported it as a bug, thanks for weighing in.

Answer (score 3):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy

http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy2

IE Edge does not support Content Security Policy Level 2, and `hash-source` belongs to level 2.

Comment: That could be the explanation, but the example works correctly in IE11 so the information there is too broad or partially missing.I don't know how Edge came about, is it possible it branched from IE11 before CSP hashes were implemented?

Comment: @StackOverflowAcc What I read from the first link is IE supports it with `X-Content-Security-Policy` header, you can give it a try.

Comment: That's IE10-11 only. Good point though, I was already using both and forgot to include it in my submission! <code>X-Content-Security-Policy</code> Makes no difference to Edge and it doesn't seem necessary for IE11 on Windows 10 either.